# Laravel: Newbie array-session ? with multiple actions

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5.3

First Laravel Project.

I want to make a page called: newfoo

The page will look like this:

```
@extends('layouts.product')
@section('title', 'Termékrészletek')
@section('main')
@parent
{{ Form::open( url=>/newfoo ) }}
<table>
<tr><td colspan=2> {{ Form::text(foo,null,required) }}</td></tr>
<tr><td><button type=submit>Add New</button></td><td><button type=?>Finish</button></td></tr>
</table>
@endsection
```

When someone type on the bar and click on the `Add New` the page reload and the "backcode" places the "foo" in a session variable $foo (or a session database). It repeats until the operator person click on the `Finish`. When he/she clicks on the finish the backcode lists the "foo"s in a table.

How can I achieve this? What's the good method?

Comment: Please watch this series. For your own good. https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017 It teaches you the basics of Laravel. In less than a day, you will can lear a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can write your values to a table and you can access it later and truncate it if you want to "destroy the session".

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the post information and manipulate it using a controller. There you can store it in a session or associate it to a model.